# перезаписывающийся список

Tags: python, классы, list

Мне нужно создать класс, который создает список фиксированный длины и если я хочу добавить больше чем длина, то перезаписывает список.
Например,

````
cycled_list = CycledList(5)
cycled_list.append(1)
cycled_list.append(2)
cycled_list.append(3)
cycled_list.append(4)
cycled_list.append(5)
cycled_list.append(6)
    ```
    Expected Output:
    ```
    [6, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    ```'
````

Я отдельно написала алгоритм для переписывающегося списка

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
size = 5
lst2 = lst1[size:]
for i in range (0,len(lst2)):
    lst1[i]=lst2[i]
    lst1=lst1.copy()
del lst1[-len(lst2):]
print (lst1)
```

Теперь то же самое нужно применить для класса

```
class CycledList:
def __init__(self, size: int):
        self._data = []
    def append(self, item):
        self._data.append (item)
        print (self._data)
```

Я не понимаю, как вывести последний результат добавления в список, он выводит все по этапам. Если я сдвину print влево, то выдаст ошибку что self не определен.

Answer (score 1):

Шаги:

- Добавил внутренний индекс `self._inner_idx`, который увеличивается при `append`
- Пока количество элементов меньше заданного в `size`, происходит добавление элементов
- После достижения размера новые элементы заменяют уже существующие. Для цикличности индекса используем деление по модулю на заданный размер `self.size`

Пример:

```
class CycledList:
    def __init__(self, size: int):
        self._inner_idx = 0
        self._data = []
        self.size = size

    def append(self, item):
        if len(self._data) < self.size:
            self._data.append(item)
        else:
            self._inner_idx %= self.size
            self._data[self._inner_idx] = item

        self._inner_idx += 1


cycled_list = CycledList(5)
cycled_list.append(1)
cycled_list.append(2)
cycled_list.append(3)
cycled_list.append(4)
cycled_list.append(5)
cycled_list.append(6)

print(cycled_list._data)
# [6, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```